# Unable to load firefox in selenium webdriver in python

Tags: python, selenium, firefox, selenium-webdriver, geckodriver

I have installed Python 3.6.2, Selenium 3.5.0 with GeckoDriver 0.18.0 and the firefox version is 54.0.1version on windows 7. I am trying to run a selenium script which is loading a firefox where i get mismatch with firefox version error. Please let me know what is the issue. The code and error message below.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_binary import FirefoxBinary
capabilities = webdriver.DesiredCapabilities().FIREFOX
capabilities["marionette"] = False
binary = FirefoxBinary('C:/Users/gopalakrishnarr/Downloads/FirefoxPortable/App/Firefox/firefox.exe')
driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_binary=binary, capabilities=capabilities, executable_path="C:/Users/gopalakrishnarr/AppData/Local/Programs/geckodriver-v0.18.0-win64/geckodriver.exe")
driver.get("http://www.google.com")
```

Error message returned:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\PythonSelenium\Sample.py", line 12, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_binary=binary, capabilities=capabilities, executable_path="C:/Users/gopalakrishnarr/AppData/Local/Programs/geckodriver-v0.18.0-win64/geckodriver.exe")
  File "C:\Users\gopalakrishnarr\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\selenium-3.5.0-py3.6.egg\selenium\webdriver\firefox\webdriver.py", line 171, in __init__
    self.binary, timeout)
  File "C:\Users\gopalakrishnarr\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\selenium-3.5.0-py3.6.egg\selenium\webdriver\firefox\extension_connection.py", line 52, in __init__
    self.binary.launch_browser(self.profile, timeout=timeout)
  File "C:\Users\gopalakrishnarr\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\selenium-3.5.0-py3.6.egg\selenium\webdriver\firefox\firefox_binary.py", line 73, in launch_browser
    self._wait_until_connectable(timeout=timeout)
  File "C:\Users\gopalakrishnarr\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\selenium-3.5.0-py3.6.egg\selenium\webdriver\firefox\firefox_binary.py", line 114, in _wait_until_connectable
    % (self.profile.path))

selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Can't load the profile. Possible firefox version mismatch. You must use GeckoDriver instead for Firefox 48+. Profile Dir: C:\Users\GOPALA~1\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpc1dfsd6w If you specified a log_file in the FirefoxBinary constructor, check it for details.
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

When you work with `Python 3.6.2`, `Selenium 3.5.0` with `GeckoDriver 0.18.0` and the Firefox browser version is `54.0.1` on `Windows 7`, you can't set the property `marionette` to `False`. Forcefully setting `marionette` to `False` will raise an `WebDriverException`. So either you have to accept the default setting of **`["marionette"] = True`** or you can explicitly set **`["marionette"]`** to **`True`** as follows:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_binary import FirefoxBinary

capabilities = webdriver.DesiredCapabilities().FIREFOX
capabilities["marionette"] = True
binary = FirefoxBinary('C:/Program Files/Mozilla Firefox/firefox.exe')
driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_binary=binary, capabilities=capabilities, executable_path="C:/Utility/BrowserDrivers/geckodriver.exe")
driver.get("http://www.google.com")
```

Comment: I tried your code and set property marionette to false or else it will not load Firefox portable 65 but it never navigates to the page! Could you help me ?thanks