# webdriver Firefox and selenium error (must use Gecko driver)

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to run `driver = webdriver.Firefox(capabilities={"marionette":False})` but got the following message:

`WebDriverException: Message: Can't load the profile. Possible firefox version mismatch. You must use GeckoDriver instead for Firefox 48+. Profile Dir: /var/folders/yl/nmd8mk3102vd3c003pbfnvs1tfpjn2/T/tmpm66g_w_2 If you specified a log_file in the FirefoxBinary constructor, check it for details.`

I'm not exactly sure how to use GeckoDriver. Is this an error with Firefox 60 / has anyone run into the same issue and are using an older version?

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to load firefox in selenium webdriver in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45692626/unable-to-load-firefox-in-selenium-webdriver-in-python)

Comment: @JeffC should have specified looking for how to fix on Mac OSX (but thanks, will use this as a guide and let you know)

Comment: Selenium version? GeckoDriver version? Firefox version?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, there IS a compatibility issue with GeckoDriver and Firefox 60. If anyone else is running into a similar issue, I recommend downloading the ESR version of Firefox, v52.8.1 or below. This resolved the issue that i was having.